# Scala subtype query

Tags: scala, types

[Nothing](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Nothing.html) in scala is subtype of every other type.

By definition, when T' is subtype of T, then it implies that in a context where T is expected, T' can be supplied.

Going by this definition, if in a context Int is expected, Nothing can be supplied.

Would it work?

Comment: A bit tired to come up with a thoughtful answer atm but this may help https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195793/how-is-nothing-a-subtype-of-every-other-type-in-scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is true:

> If you have a value of type `Nothing`, you can apply it in a context where an `Int` is expected.

We call this a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), because there are no values of type `Nothing`.

However, this statement is false:

> If in a context where an `Int` is expected, `Nothing` can be supplied.

for the same reason. `Nothing` can never be supplied, there are no values of type `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: **NO**.

As document: [Nothing](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Nothing.html): It has described `Nothing` does not have **existed instance** for its. so it's impossible to **initiate** with **Nothing** type variable, and also can't supply it in the context.